# Return NULL if Count(*) is zero

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT count(student_name) AS total_student,school_name FROM `student` 
LEFT JOIN school_info ON school_info.school_id=student.school_id
WHERE student.status='0'
```

It Returns:

```
total_student   school_name
  0               NULL
```

What I am trying to achieve is, if total_student = 0 then show no value or NULL

```
total_student   school_name
```

Could you please tell me how to do it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you're missing a `GROUP BY` clause at the bottom of your query to group by `school_name`:

```
SELECT count(student_name) AS total_student, school_name
FROM student
    LEFT JOIN school_info ON school_info.school_id = student.school_id
WHERE student.status = '0'
GROUP BY school_name
```

Then, if you want to simply not show rows where total_student = 0 then you can use the MySQL HAVING clause:

```
SELECT count(student_name) AS total_student, school_name
FROM student
    LEFT JOIN school_info ON school_info.school_id = student.school_id
WHERE student.status = '0'
GROUP BY school_name
HAVING count(student_name) > 0
```

Or, you can change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` to accomplish the same thing in this case.

Finally, if instead you want to replace 0 with null but still have rows, you could update the select statement getting the totals to:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(student_name) = 0, NULL, COUNT(student_name)) AS total_student, school_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a HAVING clause to filter out the 0 rows:

```
SELECT count(student_name) AS total_student,school_name FROM `student` 
LEFT JOIN school_info ON school_info.school_id=student.school_id
WHERE student.status='0'
HAVING total_student > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use CASE syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html